# Why are my divs messing up my javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I made a post earlier about how I was running into an issue with getting the src of an image input to change when clicking on it. At first I thought it had something to do with how I was setting up my input tag, but then later realized it was my div tags creating the issue. The thing is I still don't know why my divs are making my code not work.

this is what I currently have:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" id="Head">
      <input type="image" src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/head.png" id="headID" alt="Head" onclick="damage(this, this.id)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="ArmR">
      <input type="image" src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/armL.png" id="armRID" alt="Right Arm" onclick="damage(this, this.id)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="ArmL">
      <input type="image" src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/armR.png" id="armLID" alt="Left Arm" onclick="damage(this, this.id)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="Torso">
      <input type="image" src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/torso.png" id="torsoID" alt="Torso" onclick="damage(this, this.id)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="Groin">
      <input type="image" src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/groin.png" id="groinID" alt="Groin" onclick="damage(this, this.id)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="legR">
      <input type="image" src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/legL.png" id="legRID" alt="Right Leg" onclick="damage(this, this.id)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="legL">
      <input type="image" src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/legR.png" id="legLID" alt="Left Leg" onclick="damage(this, this.id)">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var headCount = 0;
var torsoCount = 0;
var armLCount = 0;
var armRCount = 0;
var groinCount = 0;
var legLCount = 0;
var legRCount = 0;
    
    function damage(img, imgID)
        {
        
          if(imgID == "headID")
          {
            img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/headLight.png";
        
            if(headCount == 4)
            {
              img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/headHeavy.png";
            }
        
            if(headCount == 5)
              {
                img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/headMajor.png";
              }
        
              ++headCount;
          }
        
          if(imgID == "armRID")
          {
            img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/armLLight.png";
        
            if(armRCount == 4)
            {
              img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/armLHeavy.png";
            }
        
            if(armRCount == 5)
              {
                img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/armLMajor.png";
              }
        
              ++armRCount;
          }
        
          if(imgID == "armLID")
          {
            img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/armRLight.png";
        
            if(armLCount == 4)
            {
              img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/armRHeavy.png";
            }
        
            if(armLCount == 5)
              {
                img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/armRMajor.png";
              }
        
              ++armLCount;
          }
        
          if(imgID == "torsoID")
          {
            img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/TorsoLight.png";
        
            if(torsoCount == 4)
            {
              img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/TorsoHeavy.png";
            }
        
            if(torsoCount == 5)
              {
                img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/TorsoMajor.png";
              }
        
              ++torsoCount;
          }
        
          if(imgID == "groinID")
          {
            img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/groinLight.png";
        
            if(groinCount == 4)
            {
              img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/groinHeavy.png";
            }
        
            if(groinCount == 5)
              {
                img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/groinMajor.png";
              }
        
              ++groinCount;
          }
        
          if(imgID == "legRID")
          {
            img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/legLLight.png";
        
            if(legRCount == 4)
            {
              img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/legLHeavy.png";
            }
        
            if(legRCount == 5)
              {
                img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/legLMajor.png";
              }
        
              ++legRCount;
          }
        
          if(imgID == "legLID")
          {
            img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/legRLight.png";
        
            if(legLCount == 4)
            {
              img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/legRHeavy.png";
            }
        
            if(legLCount == 5)
              {
                img.src="Images/InjuryDiagramV1/legRMajor.png";
              }
        
              ++legLCount;
          }
```

CSS:

```
#ArmR
{
  left: -295px;
}

#ArmL
{
  left: -590px;
}

#Torso
{
  top: -264px;
}

#Groin
{
  position: absolute;
}

#legR
{
  position: absolute;
}

#legL
{
  position: absolute;
}
```

For context what this is supposed to do is visually display how much damage the body has taken in a certain area. I was making it for a character sheet I was working on. I was using the divs and css so that the body is in the proper formation and place on the sheet. I'm also using bootstrap as well.

Comment: why not use `img.id` instead of` imgId` which btw does not match the condition string

Comment: without looking. My guess is your divs overlap each other